# SDL drop in performance when blitting a large texture

Tags: sdl

I am currently developing a small game in SDL in CodeBlocks and it seems i got into a little bit of trouble with surface and texture management. My current progress is getting to move a texture on-screen using the arrow keys. However, i have noticed that when loading a relatively large image, FPS drops drastically and thus the texture i move on-screen moves a lot slower.
My draw function looks like this :

```
const char* assets[5]={"assets/textures/0.tga","assets/textures/1.tga",
"assets/textures/2.tga","assets/textures/3.png","assets/textures/4.png"};
SDL_Surface* tex[5];

void DrawImage(int i, SDL_Surface* &dest, SDL_Rect &rect)
{
    if(tex[i]==NULL) tex[i] = IMG_Load(assets[i]);
    SDL_BlitSurface(tex[i], NULL, dest, &rect);
}
```

with the fourth texture in the array being the large one. If i issue any of the following :

```
DrawImage(0, screenSurface, rect);
DrawImage(1, screenSurface, rect);
DrawImage(2, screenSurface, rect);
DrawImage(4, screenSurface, rect);
```

everything runs smooth. However, if i issue:

```
DrawImage(3, screenSurface, rect);
```

and keep the texture in the window's bounds, everything runs in slow motion. Moving the texture outside the window's bounds makes everything run normal again.
The main loop looks like this :

```
bool running = true;
        while(running)
        {
            SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 0, 0, 0));
            DrawImage(3, screenSurface, rect);
            MovePlayer(rect, state);
            MoveCursor(NULL, NULL, screenSurface);
            SDL_PumpEvents();
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
            if (state[SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE])
            {
                SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
                running = false;
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `SDL_Renderer` to make use of hardware rendering. `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface` uses software rendering and can be very slow.

Comment: thanks a lot. i will try to rewrite the entire code with SDL_Renderer and SDL_Texture types then